# run multi-threading processes in aws instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, kubernetes

I have a node group in my EKS with m5.2xlarge instances (6 desired instances, 8 cores 32gb RAM for each instance)

I want to run a multi-threading processes of Gradle-tests in this node group.

The Gradle code knows to find cores and assign threads, so tests will run in parallel according to number of cores.

On MacOS and Windows my tests are working in parallel as I wish, but on k8s when running on these instances only one test is running at a time. no parallelism there.

`htop` from inside the pod itself shows 8 cores with usage average of 3% amd memory average usage is 5% !!!

Any suggestion what should be done to run multi-threading processes on AWS instances would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could disable the cpu throttling on k8s (I don't remember details, just search for it). Or check how many CPU are assigned to the running container

Comment: @gusto2 the running contains is assigned with 8 CPU's, that's why I am so confused.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? Could you attach some details so that your problem can be reproduced?